# SQL GROUP BY - Using COUNT() function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00979

I've been doing a task which involves creating a database for a hospital and I've been encountering a very frustrating error which I cannot seem to fix no matter how much research that I do.

The error I received is:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

The structure of my code for inserting the values is:

```
SELECT  CONSULTANT.S_NO, DOCTOR.D_NAME, CONSULTANT.SPEC, 
PATIENT.P_ID, PATIENT.P_NAME, COUNT(CONSULTANT.P_ID)
FROM    PATIENT, CONSULTANT, DOCTOR                            
WHERE   PATIENT.P_ID = CONSULTANT.P_ID
AND     CONSULTANT.S_NO = DOCTOR.S_NO
GROUP BY CONSULTANT.S_NO;
```

And the structure of my tables are:

```
    CREATE TABLE PATIENT (
    P_ID        NUMBER NOT NULL,
    P_NAME      CHAR(20),
    ADDRESS     VARCHAR(20),
    DOB     DATE,
    WARD_NO     NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    C_S_NO      NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PATIENT PRIMARY KEY(P_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
    S_NO        NUMBER NOT NULL,
    D_NAME      CHAR(20),
    APP_DATE    DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DOC PRIMARY KEY(S_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE CONSULTANT (
    S_NO        NUMBER NOT NULL,
    P_ID        NUMBER NOT NULL,
    SPEC        CHAR(20),
    T_CODE      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CDOC PRIMARY KEY(S_NO)
);
```

Would really appreciate any help anyone could give me on solving this dilemma.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using an aggregate function, your fields in the `SELECT` list that are not being aggregated need to be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  CONSULTANT.S_NO, DOCTOR.D_NAME, CONSULTANT.SPEC, 
PATIENT.P_ID, PATIENT.P_NAME, COUNT(CONSULTANT.P_ID)
FROM    PATIENT, CONSULTANT, DOCTOR                            
WHERE   PATIENT.P_ID = CONSULTANT.P_ID
   AND     CONSULTANT.S_NO = DOCTOR.S_NO
GROUP BY CONSULTANT.S_NO, DOCTOR.D_NAME, CONSULTANT.SPEC, PATIENT.P_ID, PATIENT.P_NAME
```

As a side note, I would also use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of the comma separated list of tables:

```
SELECT  c.S_NO, d.D_NAME, c.SPEC, p.P_ID, p.P_NAME, COUNT(c.P_ID)
FROM    PATIENT p
INNER JOIN CONSULTANT c
  ON p.P_ID = c.P_ID
INNER JOIN DOCTOR d
  ON c.S_NO = d.S_NO
GROUP BY c.S_NO, d.D_NAME, c.SPEC, p.P_ID, p.P_NAME
```

Now, since you need to add the additional fields to the `GROUP BY` this could adjust the `COUNT()` total to numbers that you are not expecting. So you might need to incorporate a sub-query to get the total count, similar to this:

```
SELECT  c1.S_NO, d.D_NAME, c1.SPEC, p.P_ID, p.P_NAME, c2.Count_P_ID
FROM    PATIENT p
INNER JOIN CONSULTANT c1
  ON p.P_ID = c1.P_ID
INNER JOIN
(
  select COUNT(c.P_ID) Count_P_ID, S_NO
  from CONSULTANT c
  group by S_NO
) c2
  ON c1.S_NO = c2.S_NO
INNER JOIN DOCTOR d
  ON c1.S_NO = d.S_NO
```

This allows you to then `GROUP BY` the one field that you initially wanted.